# "Valid signing identity not found" on New Computer

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I got new computer. Firstly i copied iOS-project from old one. Then, i refreshed profiles in organizer, but all of them got status "valid signing identity not found"
[image]

So in Keychain Access all certificates are OK

[image]

Any ideas? How should i valid all this profiles? Thnx

Comment: Do you have the private keys for the certificates in your keychain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no private keys in your certificate[image]

Go to your old mac click on **3** right click on private key and export that key give a password for the key. copy that to private key to pendrive and import that to new Mac Keychain  it asks for Password so give the password you set in old mac when Exporting. Restart the xcode it works fine

Comment: For more information check this link How to do that. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG24

Comment: right now i haven't access to my old mac. how can i recover this key from DevCenter?

Comment: If you cannot access the old mac you cannot get the .pem file. so unable to validate your certificate

Comment: If you have developer access with admin rights you can revoke the certificate and create a new Private key and Public key from developer.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

The certificates are okay, but the private keys required to sign the certificate are not here : you can see this because there is no disclose triangle near the certificate in the Keychain.app.

The keys that goes along the certificate should have a .p12 extension, but if you can't find it, your best bet is to revoke the certificates using the DevCenter, and create them back again and download them onto that new system.

Comment: where should i download .p12 file in DevCenter?

Comment: You can chose the certificate and key, and select export as "Personal Information Exchange"

Comment: could you explain more detail, step by step

Comment: Ok, here goes. In your old Mac, goes to Keychain.app and select Keys in the Keychain sidebar. Then select your private key, the one you used to request the developer certificate, and export the private key as a .p12 file (File > Export > Personal Information Exchange). You'll be asked to give it a password you will need later to resinstall it. No get this file to your new mac, double click on it, and type in the password. Done

Answer (score 1):

If you have your private keys in your old mac you can create your .p12 file like this:
http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-do-i-create-p12-file.html

But if you do not, you have to revoke your old certificate and create a new one.
This is such a pain sometimes. Recently I had to face this. The certificates may appear but you do not have the private keys with you. For a complete guide click below: 
http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2013/09/ios-code-sign-in-complete-walkthrough.html